# Woocommerce aggregate report by each person type sold - filtered by date range for bookable product

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Does any functionality or SQL query exist to build a report on bookable products sold by the individual person type filtered by a date range? I'd like to see a count of each person type sold in each day across a month.

If not where are the individual sold person types stored in the woocommerce SQL tables?